# Ref.current is null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to solve the problem, but I don't understand what the error is. I found out that a null in a ref can appear because the object is not mounted. But I put the function in useEffect, but that didn't help either, what could be wrong?

I got error: wrapper.current is null after click on Component.

My step 1: everything is OK
My component works fine. I can open and close it.

```
import { useRef, useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function Dropdown(props) {
  const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState(false);
  const dropdownWrapper = useRef(null);
  const dropdown = useRef(null);

  const handleClick = (event) => {
    setIsActive(true);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
      if (
        !dropdownWrapper.current.contains(event.target) &&
        !dropdown.current.contains(event.target)
      ) {
        setIsActive(false);
      }
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <div
        ref={dropdownWrapper}
        onClick={handleClick}
        className="relative flex w-full cursor-pointer"
      >
        {props.children} {props.content}
        <div
          ref={dropdown}
          className={`${!isActive ? "hidden" : ""} 
          absolute -left-0 top-full z-30 mb-[4px] flex w-full flex-col`}
        >
          <div
            className={`scroll flex max-h-[310px] min-w-max flex-col overflow-hidden overflow-y-auto rounded-b-[8px] bg-blue-50 py-[8px] shadow-mm-1 dark:bg-gray-800 ${
              props.apart && "mt-[4px] rounded-[8px]"
            }`}
          >
            <>{props.menu}</>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export { Dropdown };
```

[image]

My step 2.

I go to other Component: Search.
[image]

Here I have different code (without useEffect). And when I click - I got message:

[image]

On other page. When I return to Dropdown page and click on them I got a lot of messages about errors in this Dropdown and Search Components.

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";

export default function Search(props) {
  const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState(false);
  const wrapper = useRef(null);
  const result = useRef(null);

  const handleClick = (event) => {
    setIsActive(true);
    document.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
      if (
        !wrapper.current.contains(event.target) &&
        !result.current.contains(event.target)
      ) {
        setIsActive(false);
      }
    });
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div
        ref={wrapper}
        onClick={handleClick}
        className={`relative flex w-full min-w-[360px] max-w-[720px] cursor-pointer ${
          isActive ? "rounded-t-[32px]" : "rounded-full"
        }  bg-gray-800 `}
      >
        {props.children}
        <div
          ref={result}
          className={`${!isActive ? "hidden" : ""} 
          absolute -left-0 top-full z-30 mb-[4px] flex w-full flex-col `}
        >
          <div
            className={`flex max-h-[310px] min-w-max flex-col overflow-hidden overflow-y-auto rounded-b-[32px] bg-blue-50 py-[8px] shadow-mm-1 dark:bg-gray-800`}
          >
            <>{props.result}</>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export { Search };
```

And finally. If I refresh the page - everything work fine until I click on another component. How to fix that?

Comment: The problem is ```!dropdownWrapper.current.contains``` the contains function here does not exist on null. a quick fix would be to safeguard against nulls here.

```!dropdownWrapper?.current?.contains```  and do the same on the one below. That should work.

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep that in mind! I came up with another method half a day later (10 minutes after the question here, of course). I will publish it now. The error is gone (at least it does not occur anymore, I tried switching between pages and clicking on components 10+ times)

Answer (score 0):

I add refs in the useEffect and the error is gone. If you have any recommendations, I'd love to hear it!

```
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";

export default function Dropdown(props) {
  const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState(false);
  const wrapper = useRef();
  const dropdown = useRef();

  const handleClick = (event) => {
    setIsActive(true);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const wrapperRef = wrapper.current;
    const dropdownRef = dropdown.current;

    document.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
      if (
        !wrapperRef.contains(event.target) &&
        !dropdownRef.contains(event.target)
      ) {
        setIsActive(false);
      }
    });
  }, [isActive]);

  return (
    <>
      <div
        ref={wrapper}
        onClick={handleClick}
        className="relative flex w-full cursor-pointer"
      >
        {props.children} {props.content}
        <div
          ref={dropdown}
          className={`${!isActive ? "hidden" : ""} 
          absolute -left-0 top-full z-30 mb-[4px] flex w-full flex-col`}
        >
          <div
            className={`scroll flex max-h-[310px] min-w-max flex-col overflow-hidden overflow-y-auto rounded-b-[8px] bg-blue-50 py-[8px] shadow-mm-1 dark:bg-gray-800 ${
              props.apart && "mt-[4px] rounded-[8px]"
            }`}
          >
            <>{props.menu}</>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export { Dropdown };
```